# Переписать готовый запрос в другом виде

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT DISTINCT Book.Name AS BookName, Author.Name AS AuthorName 
FROM Book JOIN Author ON Author.ID = Book.AuthorID 
JOIN Rating ON Rating.BookID = Book.ID 
WHERE CAST(ReleaseYear AS varchar(4)) 
NOT LIKE '%' + CAST(Rate AS varchar(2)) + '%'
```

Всем добрый вечер, подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли написать этот запрос как то иначе. Само задание запроса выглядит так.

> Выбрать список книг с именем автора, у которых есть оценка не
>   совпадающая ни с одной из цифр в годе выпуска книги. Книги не должны
>   повторяться

Я написал этот запрос, но он не подходит, хотя выполняет то, что мне нужно.

Comment: если оценка может быть больше 9, то ваше решение не верно

Comment: а можете пожалуйста подсказать как тогда лучше сделать?

Comment: с типами данных посмотрите сами, как оно хранится у вас https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d0b281517e31327c1c7da2869564be7b

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis Если могут быть оценки за пределами целых 0..9, то само задание некорректно - там написано слово "цифра".

Comment: *он не подходит, хотя выполняет то, что мне нужно* Вот с этого момента поподробнее. Почему - не подходит? если нужная функция выполняется...

Comment: @Akina я сдал данный запрос на проверку и мне пришло в ответ что запрос верный, но можно записать иначе

Comment: Пффф... это не "переписать запрос", а "угадать мысли преподавателя". Попробуй вместо LIKE использовать, например, INSTR()...

Comment: @Akina ну мое предположение связано именно с наличием оценок больше 9 (которые не считаются цифрами). А в остальном - согласен с Вами - попытка угадать мысли другого человека:)

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis обожаю нашу систему образования

Comment: @AndreyFreiz это задание по какой теме? что сейчас проходите?

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis обычные SQL запросы к мелкой базе данных

Comment: @Akina предлагаешь вместо NOT LIKE '%' + CAST(Rate AS varchar(2)) + '%' написать INSTR('%' + CAST(Rate AS varchar(2)) + '%')?

Comment: А проценты-то там нафига? INSTR() тупо ищет подстроку в строке.

Comment: только в MS SQL это Charindex

Comment: @Akina SQL явно моя слабость, можешь сказать как сделать правильно. буду премного благодарен

Comment: Возможно вместо `DISTINCT` и `JOIN Rating` от вас хотят `EXISTS`.

Comment: @i-one  можешь пожалуйста  в ответе написать как будет выглядеть запрос в  таком случае?

Comment: ставлю на `rating not in (substing(year,0,1), substring(year, 1,1)....)`

Comment: или может быть еще `except` имелся в виду. Вы добавьте примеры исходных данных для выборки, чтобы понятно было. вам бы тут разных вариантов накидали в ответах )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> можно ли написать этот запрос как то иначе

Вместо `DISTINCT` и `JOIN Rating` можно использовать коррелированный подзапрос c `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT
    Book.Name AS BookName,
    Author.Name AS AuthorName 
FROM Book
    JOIN Author ON Author.ID = Book.AuthorID 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Rating
    WHERE Rating.BookID = Book.ID
        AND CAST(ReleaseYear AS varchar(4)) NOT LIKE '%' + CAST(Rate AS varchar(2)) + '%'
    )
```

(перенесли таблицу `Rating` и связанные с ней предикаты в `EXISTS`).